# Symbol recognition on a scanned image (map)

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, image, vectorization

I have a specific task and I'm looking for possible approaches. What I'm trying to do is this:

I have a high resolution (600dpi) scanned, and georeferenced image of a map, and I need to be able to automatically find a certain list of map symbols on it (the map is old, so even the same symbols may differ from each other since it was made right before the digital age), and then place a point (or other vector type element) on the same location. So far I was able to separate the needed color (black) onto a different (greyscale) image so now I would need to find a way to recognise the shapes of the symbols(some are really simple like letters, an other are specific lines).

Is there software or environment where I could do this the easy way, or only if I write something new myself (sadly not an expert). So far I looked at QGIS, GRASS, SAGA GIS solutions but I didn't find anything that would work with shape or form. The GIS way is my first approach since I'm not familiar with image editing, but if it could be done outside a GIS (perhaps mark the location of the symbols or change their color on the image) I could georeference it later. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What you are trying to do is pattern recognition in images (such as looking for and recognizing faces in CCTV for security). There has been lots written on this in non-GIS literature so perhaps you need to start there.